# How to stop highlight when any bar is clicked in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using barChart of `MPAndroidChart` library. My problem is whenever I click any bar of that bar chart its color change something like an overlay. I have tried several techniques but nothing is working. I have tried following codes :

```
    barChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
```

Upper line do this trick for me but it also disables click event, that means if I set `HighlightPerTapEnabled = false` then my onValue selected listener does not fire anymore. I also have tried below two lines but nothing is working as my expectation.

```
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
```

All i want just to remove this change of color when a user clicks any bar of that barChart. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The accepted answer does not do what you ask. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 12):

You just need to disable the `HighLight` property on `BarData`

```
BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
data.setHighlightEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This disables the onValue listener.

Answer (score 4):

from version 3.1.0,  'barDataSet.setHighLightAlpha(0)' will do the job

Answer (score 2):

```
   barDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    barDataSet.setHighLightAlpha(0);
```

This will snippet will help to remove selection color

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers is working. However, I solved this issue by :

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Year : 2017");
 barDataSet.setHighLightAlpha(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
dataSet.highLightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Answer (score 0):

for the newer versions , you can use the code below

```
mBarChart.isHighlightPerTapEnabled=false
```